# Add new buttons to MPV uosc UI

Tags: video, user-interface, media-player, mpv

[uosc](https://github.com/tomasklaen/uosc) is a customizable UI for MPV player.

Looking into the `uosc.conf` file, there is this line about how to create new buttons:

```
'command:{icon}:{command}' - button that executes a {command} when pressed\
```

Also, about icons:

```
{icon} - parameter used to specify an icon name (example: face)

you can pick one here: [https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material+Icons&icon.style=Rounded](https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material+Icons&icon.style=Rounded)
```

Buttons have to be added to the `uosc.conf` line that starts with `controls=`.

But how exactly to create these new buttons? A few examples would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Available MPV options/actions are like those from `input.conf`. For example, [for a Play/pause](https://www.reddit.com/r/mpv/comments/x8k722/comment/jbuuf90/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) button something like this has to be added to `controls=` line in `uosc.conf`:

```
cycle:play_arrow:pause:no=pause/yes=play_arrow?Play/Pause
```

(The part after `?` is the title you want to see when hovering the button; the above involves the `cycle` option, discussed in `uosc.conf`: `cycle:{default_icon}:{prop}[@{owner}]:{value1}[={icon1}][!]/{valueN}[={iconN}][!]` etc.)

Rewind/forward buttons would require the `command` option, mentioned in the question:

```
command:fast_forward:seek 10?Forward 10s
command:fast_rewind:seek -10?Rewind 10s
```

[image]

For zoom:

```
command:zoom_out:add panscan -0.1?Zoom IN
command:zoom_in:add panscan +0.1?Zoom OUT
```

[image]

Beside mpv internal actions, other programs can be used from within mpv with `run`. For example, in order to [download subtitles with SMPlayer's](https://www.reddit.com/r/mpv/comments/120w6ts/search_subtitles_with_smplayer_directly_from_mpv/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) "Find subtitles" option, we can use:

```
command:download:run smplayer -actions "show_find_sub_dialog pause size_75" ${path}?Download subtitle (SMPlayer)
```

[image]

Here is an example of the entire buttons line (from which I have replaced the default "speed" button with Rewind,Play/Pause and forward buttons):

```
controls=menu,gap,command:download:run smplayer -actions "show_find_sub_dialog pause size_75" ${path}?Download subtitle (SMPlayer),gap,subtitles,<has_many_audio>audio,<has_many_video>video,<has_many_edition>editions,<stream>stream-quality,gap,space,command:fast_rewind:seek -10?Rewind 10s,cycle:play_arrow:pause:no=pause/yes=play_arrow?Play/Pause,command:fast_forward:seek 10?Forward 10s,space,gap,prev,items,next,gap,fullscreen,gap,command:zoom_out:add panscan -0.1?Zoom OUT,gap,command:zoom_in:add panscan +0.1?Zoom IN
```

[image]